# TYPO3 - New, edit or delete action ignore redirect to list view

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

New, edit or delete action ignore redirect to list view, although it's defined in the controller. I added some fields and changed key definitions in the controller and now the new, edit or delete action ignores redirect to list view. Everything else works, it does create new or edit records. What am I missing?

Update action in controller:

```
/**
 * action update
 *
 * @param \Vendor\Car\Domain\Model\Car $record
 * @return void
 */
public function updateAction(\Vendor\Car\Domain\Model\Car $record) {
    $this->addFlashMessage('The object was updated.', '', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::ERROR);
    $this->carRepository->update($record);

    $this->redirect('list');
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code of the action, please?

Comment: I provided above. Is 'Exclude from speaking URL' for List View and 'Hide in Menus' for the Detail view not the correct approach? With this now it's working ...

Comment: You don't need `Exclude from speaking URL`, that's only for the purpose you don't want to have a speaking URL on that page.

The action looks good. On which page are you when calling this action? List? Detail? Another one?

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it was setting:

```
-List[42]  // List View       -> 'Exclude from speaking URL'
--Detail[43]  // Detail View  -> 'Hide in Menus'
```